blazor - bind-value:after passing parameters
this happens before my datagrid entity is changed:
 Change="@(args => onselectrowpremadeinfo(ProductCareInfo))"

usually i would use bind-value:after, but i don't understand how to pass an argument. if i try, it says i need to return an action

You could try
@bind-Value:after="@(()=>{onselectrowpremadeinfo(ProductCareInfo);})"
...
    private void onselectrowpremadeinfo(ProductCareInfoType info)
    {
    }

@bind-Value:after doesn't offer EventArgs
